# Winforms Label Text property not displaying \t tab character

Tags: c#, winforms

This should be very simple.

I have a Label control on my Form and I am trying to put a tab character between text

```
Label.Text = "Is there a\ttab";
```

The output is "Is there atab";

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tab is actually a non-printing character—or rather, a control character. What it does is entirely dependent on the application. What exactly do you expect? 8 spaces? 4 spaces? As many spaces as needed to get to a multiple of 8 columns? Indentation of the following text by one cm?

To put it short: The `Label` control doesn't support tabs. Actually, Label just uses normal graphics routines for rendering its text and how should *they* know what you intend to do with your tab character?

If you need to display that character as a number of spaces, then you should replace it by that number of spaces.

Comment: I guess my code should be:
string tab = "    ";
label.text = "Is there a" + tab + "tab";

Comment: If you want a space there, maybe. You still didn't specify what you expect it to display.

Comment: I want it to display whatever a tab is which is about 4-5 spaces

Comment: @Jon: Well, as noted, whatever a tab is *is up to your program*. There is no single right way of representing a tab. Go ahead, ask your printer, your favorite text editor and your favorite word processing application what a tab actually *is*. You'll get three very different answers.

Comment: @Jon: If you want to display spaces, then you need to put spaces there. It's as simple as that.

Comment: This is wrong. There is a visual difference in Tab spaces and normal spaces. In Word, or Visual Studio*, if you press space, it is selected as if it were a single, long invisible character. In Visual Studio, you have the option of a Tab being many spaces, or a single, long invisible "character". How do we get the invisible dude to come up?

Comment: @0550: please take the time to read my answer and comments. I was arguing that there is *no single right thing to do* when encountering a tab and the person asking didn't state clearly what they want and need. The Label control itself does nothing with a tab character. Whatever you want to do with it, you'll have to do yourself.

Comment: Some Windows controls before .NET used to support tab stops. Apparently Microsoft did away with that functionality.

Comment: @Suncat2000: Text boxes and list boxes still support them. Note that Windows Forms only wraps native controls anyway, so you can access all that via the Windows API as well.

Comment: Indeed Textbox supports them so Label could and should do too.. Oh well.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to add tabs (`"\t"`) to a dropdown list of items.  The items have a `ToString` method that gives about 3 words concatenated together.  They did not line up.  For example:

- 1-I 45
- 123-AB 511
- 123456-MMM 611

A long list like this is hard to read.  So I used `string.Format` like this:

```
string.Format("{0,6}-{1,-4} {2}",id,name,num);
```

The number after the comma will right align/pad if positive and left align/pad if negative.
Then I changed my font in the Combobox to be monospaced, like Courier New, and you get something like this:

```
     1-I    45
   123-AB   511
123456-MMM  611
```

That is much easier for a user to read.

Comment: This is the true solution to the initial question. Easy, simple and elegant. My green check is for you @Jess

Answer (score 3):

Nothing, windows forms labels are very limited in functionality and don't support the \t character.

A (slightly awkward) alternative might be:

```
label1.Text = "test\ting\t123".Replace("\t","    ");
```

Comment: Really? Weird. Any alternative approaches?

Comment: Sadly, the only thing I can think of (not very helpful) is to use WPF instead :(

Answer (score 3):

Old thread, but since none of the answers seemed to work for me, I will go ahead and throw in my 2 cents. I could not get a "\t" or even use manual spaces to add spacing to the label. What I ended up doing was using alt code alt-255 5 times. This worked like a charm. Gotta love total hacks...

Answer (score 1):

Right, to insert a tab, just add the spaces desired.

If you want to offset the next by a specified length, you could try

```
int offset_text = 20;
label1.Text = "Is there a".PadRight(offset_text)+"Tab";
label2.Text = "More Text".PadRight(offset_text)+"Too";
```

Comment: Are you sure this works?  PadRight will have no effect in this case because "Is there a" is longer than 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a literal string and you should be good to go...

```
label1.Text = @"Test for            Tab";
```

Where that big space is where I actually hit tab three times...hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. A textbox does instead a label accept Tabs. So if you change the label in a textbox, the pro

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -2):

Just click in the arrow at the right of the Text property of the label (click in the Text property content and the drop-down-arrow will show up).  A box for text-editing will open, and in that box you can use Enter, Tab, and so on.