# How to insert a tabSpace into a string?

Tags: c#, winforms, string

I'm trying to insert a tabSpace into a string:

```
string ab = "a" + "\t" + "b"
```

But I got a square instead of space.
Please help.

Comment: Did you observe this 'square' on a control's text field?

Comment: I create a label.Text from this string

Comment: Mark's answer below is the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Note that there is no need to use string concatenation. This achieves the same effect:

```
string ab = "a\tb";
```

The problem you have is not with *creating* the string, but with *displaying* the string. You are probably using a control that doesn't support displaying tabs. It might be better to replace the tabs with spaces.

**Related**

- [Winforms Label Text property not displaying \t tab character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154623/winforms-label-text-property-not-displaying-t-tab-character)

Comment: is it then possible to right align that string (because it is multiline)

Comment: @Buena: Can't you just use two separate labels?

Comment: No, lines are created from dgvRows, it could be 5 lines

Comment: @Buena: How about a RichTextBox then? You can make it non-editable.

Comment: Hm, I'll try. Thanks to EveryOne. But every day I find some limitations in C# and VS.